# Restore backup made with wbadmin in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I made a manual backup (windows 7, console) using wbadmin:

```
wbadmin Start backup –backupTarget:H: -include:D:
```

How do I restore from that backup?

The wbadmin's commands set in windows 7 is limited to actually taking backups and some info commands.
The backup is not showing in 'Backup and Restore' program.